# AWS Architecture: Which component to use in my case?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the same application codebase, which is deployed to several Beanstalk environments in different regions. Each Beanstalk environment is used by a specific group of users (group A, group B and group C). At the moment, I need to change the environment URL whenever I want to send HTTP requests to a specific environment.

Can you recommend an AWS component (X) that can forward my requests to the desired environment? The flow I want to implement is like:

- At first, I tell the component X that I belong to user group A (or B, C)
- Component X will answer me which Beanstalk instance I should forward all of my requests to.
- I save the response from X locally. I use this information to forward my requests to the target Beanstalk environment.
- When I no longer need this information (eg when I want to switch and call another Beanstalk environment, when I log out from my current user...), I delete the information locally.

This loop starts again next time I want to send requests to a specific beanstalk.

Comment: Route53? Not sure what you are asking for. Can you clarify.

Comment: It sounds like you have a solution already, looking up the URL in your code, and then storing it and using it in your application during the user session. What specific problems are you encountering in your current solution? What specific feature are you looking for AWS to solve for you?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will work as a proxy between my client and the beanstalks. As you said, that is the destination to which I  do lookup and get back the url.